# Looping through function causes error and fails on first change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have here the following script which is causing me some errors:

```
var sections = ["#general_info", "#address_records", "#employment_history", "#driver_experience", "#military_experience", "#eeo_survey", "#psp_notice", "#eva"];
for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){ 
    $(sections[i]).find('input, select').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            validate();
            $(this).closest('.placement').find('.module-heading').removeClass('module-heading-bad');
            $(this).closest('.placement').find('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-ok text-success');
            $(this).closest('.placement').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger');
            $(sections[i]).find('input, select').each(function(){
                if($(this).closest('div').hasClass('has-error')){
                    $(this).closest('.placement').find('.module-heading').addClass('module-heading-bad');
                    $(this).closest('.placement').find('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger');
                    $(this).closest('.placement').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-ok text-success');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

function validate(){
    var driving_qs = ['driving_exp_qa', 'driving_exp_qb', 'driving_exp_qc', 'driving_exp_qd'];
    for( var i = 0; i < driving_qs.length; i++){
        if($('input[name='+driving_qs[i]+']:checked').val()){
            $('input[name='+driving_qs[i]+']').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $('input[name='+driving_qs[i]+']').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
        }else{
            $('input[name='+driving_qs[i]+']').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            $('input[name='+driving_qs[i]+']').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
        }
    }
    var fields = [{
        selector: $('.not-empty'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty]
    },{
        selector: $('.email'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty, isEmail]
    },{
        selector: $('.number'),
        validations: [ isNotEmpty, isNumber]
    },{
        selector: $('.number-noreq'),
        validations: [isNumberNotRequired]
    }];
    $('.form-control').closest('div').removeClass('has-error');
    var i = 0, k = 0, z = 0, j = fields.length, item, selector, fn, info;
    for(; i < j; i++){
        item = fields[i];
        for(k = 0; k < item.validations.length; k++){
            fn = item.validations[k];
            for( z = 0; z < item.selector.length; z++){
                selector = $(item.selector[z]);
                info = selector.closest('div');
                if(info)
                    var result = fn(selector.val());
                if(result){
                    info.removeClass("has-error");
                    info.addClass('has-success');
                }else{
                    info.removeClass('has-success');
                    info.addClass("has-error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script works perfectly fine if I am running it without the for loop in front of it. Here is a quick step by step of what my code does (note: this is without the for loop):

1. Locate the section in code and find each input an select field
2. Assign the change event to each target input and select field
3. On change find closest span of class placement, and fine the first module heading and perform all the adding and removing of classes, just to refresh the heading to  a success heading if no errors exist below.
4. Find all the inputs and selects and check for errors, if they exists return false, and add the error classes back on everything

This script will work all the way to the end of each section like it is supposed to do. However after I tried to do this with the `for loop`, it created a success scenario after only one input. Why is this happening, and is it even possible to have this function inside a loop like I am currently doing?

Also below I have included samples of the html mark-up

```
<!-- this tag serves no purpose other than being a bookmark for scripting -->
<span class='placement'>
    <!-- Section 1: General Information  -->
    <div id='general-heading' class='row module-heading module-heading-bad general' data-toggle='#general_info'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <h4 class='text-info '>General Information<div id='general-confirmation' class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign pull-right text-danger'></div></h4>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='general_info' class='app-section'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-xs-12'>
                <div class='form-group row'>
                    <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>    
                        <label class='control-label'>First Name<span class='req'> *</span></label><br />
                        <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty' id='first_name' value="<?=$first_name?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Middle Name</label><br />
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='middle_name' value="<?=$middle_name?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</span>
```

Comment: You're missing a `</div>` at the end of your code, and a pair of `{}` for the `if(info)`.

Comment: the div part is just a sample I pulled its not an actual chunk of code, so that div is there but that's for proofreading!

Comment: Always try to post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. This means that the code you post should work to illustrate the problem you're having.

Comment: i see slight similarities to your reference, but it's not enough to determine an answer for what I'm doing here.

Comment: To rule out the obvious problem people encounter when moving code inside a for loop, try wrapping everything inside the for loop in a closure: `for(...){ function(e,i){...original code...}(e,i)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this block of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){ 
    $(sections[i]).find('input, select').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            ...
            $(sections[i]).find('input, select').each(function(){
                ...
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Is that it uses the variable `i`, which will have changed when the `function()` inside `change` is run.

In your case, the simplest way to fix it would be by using the `forEach` function instead of a for loop, and not using the index at all:

```
sections.forEach(function(section){ 
    $(section).find('input, select').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            ...
            $(section).find('input, select').each(function(){
                ...
                }
            });
        });
    });
})
```

This will ensure that the `i` you mean is different each time.

Comment: excellent that you very much! that makes sense now that I think about what you said about the i changing

Comment: @MarkHill you're welcome. Also, if you use the forEach method, you can replace `sections[i]` with the first argument to the forEach callback, which is `e`. But rename the `e` variable first to make it more readable.

Comment: ah thank you this has been a very helpful learning experience